# Replace **Foo** to <strong>Foo</stong> (regex)?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, markdown

Is there such a **preg_replace** I can do here? I really don't speak regex.

I am to filter WordPress post and intended to do such a replacement. I don't want to enumerate all the `**`s one by one if there is better / faster way to do that.

Something like with every even `**` do this, and every odd `**` do that, or so.

Comment: Something like this: http://regex101.com/r/qK0bV9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$patterns = array("/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/", ...);
$replacements = array("<strong>$1</strong>", ...);
$result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $subject);
```

Comment: Might be better to use `(.+)` here instead of being specific to letters only

Comment: Though you'll need to adjust it so it still captures the closing `**`.. sorry: `([^*.]+)`

Comment: Thanks! Err, any way to add more similar filter to a single replace call? Like backticks to `<code>` tags or similar.

Comment: @Geri Edited, take a look ;) you can pass an array to preg_replace

Comment: Don't escape `*` when it's inside of `[]`

Answer (score 1):

This one will allow for inner strings that contain single asterisks such as "** Foo * Bar **":

```
match: (\*{2})([^\1]*?)\1
replace: <strong>\2</strong>
```